# VBA scraping with same class name but different innertext

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Scraping value on a website but turned out the value that I need shared the same class name as the others.

HTML code

```
<tr class="table_bdrow1_style">
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="table_bdtext_style">1.</td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="table_bdtext_style">
            <div id="a">
                  "0.8948"                
              </div>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center" class="table_bdtext_style">December 19, 2016</td>
</tr>
```

I need the value of second line (0.8948) and third line - the date value (December 19, 2016) but the code I am using only shows me the first value (1).

```
extract1 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("table_bdtext_style")(1).innerText
Cells(4, "A").Value = extract1
```

Not sure how can I extract the second and third but not the first value. Anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the respective index in your extract call:

```
' for second tag
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("table_bdtext_style")(2).innerText

' for third tag
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("table_bdtext_style")(3).innerText
```